# When do I go through customs?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, airports

I'm flying out of New York JFK airport, transferring at LAX in Los Angeles, and then flying to Melbourne Australia.  The entire trip I'm flying with Qantas.

Will I have to gather my checked luggage and go through customs at LAX?  My concern is that I only have an hour and 10 minutes between flights and am unsure if I'll be able to make it to my connecting flight on time.

Comment: If you booked this as one ticket, then that means your airline has guaranteed your connection, and so they'll rebook you onto a different flight if you do miss it as a result of not having enough time.

Answer (score 9):

> Will I have to gather my checked luggage and go through customs at LAX?

No.  The US does not have systematic exit controls.  There may be CBP officers interviewing people at the gate; they do select some flights for this treatment.  You will not need to retrieve your bags at LAX, however.  They will be checked through to Melbourne.

> When do I go through customs?

You will pass through Australia's immigration and customs controls in Melbourne.

Comment: I know some flights to Melbourne from North America stop first in Sydney in which case you'd clear Customs in Sydney.  Non-stop flights to Melbourne will clear Customs in Melbourne.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie the question indicates a non-stop flight from Los Angeles to Melbourne.

Comment: Yep, Stack Exchange threads last for years so I wanted completeness for other readers.